# Google Places API autocomplete result mismatched the selected suggestion

Tags: google-maps-api-3

After a day debugging my code, I've realized that GOOGLE PLACES Autocomplete API is returning mismatched place according to the selected suggestion.

The issue is for this specific place. I don't know if there is any more places on same situation.

I've tested autocomplete function from google's example website.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I start typing "Rua Almeida Garrett, São João do Estoril" on input box until it become available on autocomplete suggestion. After click on the suggestion the result is "Rua Almeida Garrett, São Domingos de Rana".

It returns a road with same name "Rua Almeida Garrett" but on a different location, as you can see on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljb31.png).

I've tried to perform the same search on Google Maps website, but here the result is ok. it managed to distinguish the different locations.

is it a bug?

Comment: I get the expected result (São Pedro do Estoril;
São Pedro do Estoril Estoril Lisboa), at least if I choose first entry.

Comment: Did you search for " Rua Almeida Garrett, São João do Estoril" ? because i am getting " Rua Almeida Garrett, São Domingos de Rana" as the result

Comment: As I read your question, the search was for "São Pedro do Estoril", there are no other addresses in the question (other than the claimed result).

Comment: I've edited my question in order to make my self clear

Comment: My guess would be a data issue in the places API.